# I can't bake Vertex paint

Tags: baking, vertex-paint

I have been trying to bake my high resolution model's Texture paint or Vertex paint all day today without any luck. Lastly I tried the Vertex paint, but here's what happens:

this is the high poly mesh and the Vertex paint on it

[image]

this is the low poly mesh with the baked texture:

[image]

The thing I'm trying to do is to texture or vertex paint the high res mesh and baked it onto the low poly retopologized version. Because the high resolution and difference of the two meshes I cannot UV wrap the high res model. What am I doing wrong with the Vertex paint?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When dealing with complex troubleshooting questions like this one, please provide a .blend file. It's often necessary to diagnose the problem

Comment: I can't see how you use the vertex paint. To me, it looks like you bake the Ambient Occlusion, a white diffuse color, and lighting. Well, everything except the vertex color ;-) The AO and the lighting can create these strange artifacts, especially when you don't use any Extrusion (0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To actually use the vertex color the material of your high-poly should have a *Vertex Color* node. Has it one?

[image: bake preparation]

To bake the color plug the *Vertex Color* node into an *Emission* node and bake the *Emit* type. Move both objects to the same location, enable them for render. Then use `[X]` *Active to Selected*, and increase the *Extrusion* value a bit. When baking the *Image Texture* node in the low-poly object's material should not be connected just selected.

This is the result using the baked image (*Image Texture* node is now connected to the *Principled BSDF*):

[image: result]

Comment: Thank you, I was missing the vertex color node! It works now!